# Submit Cognito Form results back to the user who filled the form

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I have the responses filled by a user sent to the user's email address? I can collect the email of the user in a field. But is there any way to have the responses sent to that user automatically?

I've seen I can have an email sent to the user if the form contains payments, but what if it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

I am part of the Cognito Forms team - this feature was added this morning under our new [Submission Settings](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/13/building-forms/confirmation-emails).

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Support for customizable email notifications will be included in our December release next week.

[image]

You can learn more about and follow the progress of this feature on our [Trello board](https://trello.com/c/GPZadDc0).